# What is a Cuddly Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

This is in the spirit of the What is a Word/Phrase™ series started by JLee, etc. You know the drill by now.

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Cuddly Word™.

Use the following examples to find the rule. The alphabetical ordering of the Cuddly Words™ is not relevant.

[image: Cuddly Words]

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Cuddly Words™,Non-Cuddly Words™  
AMBLE,STROLL  
ANNA,JANE  
APPLE,ORANGE  
BUNT,WHACK  
EAST,WEST  
EGO,PSYCHE  
IDO,ESPERANTO  
LASSI,DOOGH  
REGAN,GONERIL  
RIM,BRINK  
RUES,REGRETS  
STAT,IMMEDIATELY  
TAGINES,NAVARINS  
TAXI,HANSOM
```

Comment: Is DOOGH supposed to be DOUGH?

Comment: You can use Microsoft Excel to create the table. Just follow the guidelines of previous puzzles for formatting. You can also edit a previous puzzles, copy everything, and then edit what you need to. That's how I got the CSV working.

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's similar to a lassi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think a Cuddly Word™ is

> one for which you can add exactly one letter at the start and one at the end, and still get a word. Admittedly in some cases an obscure one.

Perhaps more specifically

> you can add the *same* letter at the start and the end. [Edit by Paolo: So a Cuddly Word™ is one you can "hug" with the "arms" of the hug each being the same letter.]

So:

> rAMBLEr
>  pANNAn -- in comments Will suggests sANNAs or maybe nANNAn and Sconibulus suggests tANNAt; I guess Will's first answer is the intended one as his second one is slang and Sconibulus's looks like a proper noun, but all three are pretty credible.
>  dAPPLEd
>  uBUNTu (does this count? has it been sufficiently naturalized into the language?)
>  yEASTy
>  bEGOb
>  wIDOw
>  cLASSIc
>  oREGANo
>  pRIMp
>  tRUESt
>  eSTATe
>  sTAGINESs
>  aTAXIa

All the words for which I have good examples fit the more specific pattern. All the options for ANNA are kinda obscure.

I have checked only the first few of the stated Non-Cuddly Words and they don't fit even the broader one. I bet the more specific pattern is the one intended.

Comment: Oregano for Regan?

Comment: yeah, I was editing that (and other comments) in while you were making the comment :-).

Comment: (and feeling very stupid for not having seen it immediately)

Comment: [ANNA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanna_(dish)) possibly

Comment: ah yes, that's pluralizable. Could well be.

Comment: [Another possibility](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nannan) I guess

Comment: All those suggestions for ANNA are now in the answer and credited appropriately. (If you prefer to minimize spoilers you might want to remove them from the comments, but I personally don't mind.)

Comment: Thank you to whoever put the question in the right format. Gareth - you've got it. The more specific method is the correct one. The solution for BUNT does count - it is in Collins English Dictionary as a naturalised word. Finally, the solution given for ANNA is not correct. None of the letters are used more than once. You can consider the word ANNA itself as a hint to its own solution, and I'm sure you will have heard of it.

Comment: Oh, so it's HANNAH then...

Comment: Is it really necessary to figure out each word? Isn't the goal of the puzzle to just find the rule?

Comment: Will, that's it. Accepting as solved. greenturtle3141 - I suppose not, but I think it makes it more interesting for everyone if the answers are found.