# What is a Contradictory Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub><sup>This is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what+is+a%22+word+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What+is+%22+%22Word%22+-missing+user%3A463+is%3Aquestion) puzzles.</sup></sub>

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Contradictory Word™**.

Use the following examples to find the rule:

| Contradictory Words™ | Not Contradictory Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| TOUCH | TEXT |
| LIMITED | LATE |
| BRUTAL | EXPLOSIVE |
| HEALTHY | GREEN |
| CUDDLY | SHARP |
| FINAL | FIRST |
| ODD | EVEN |
| TIGHT | BIND |
| UNION | COMPOSITE |

Some words are neither Contradictory Words™ nor Not Contradictory Words™.

Should you need it, here's a CSV version for easier copy-pasting:

```
Contradictory Words™, Not Contradictory Words™           
TOUCH,TEXT
LIMITED,LATE
BRUTAL,EXPLOSIVE
HEALTHY,GREEN
CUDDLY,SHARP
FINAL,FIRST
ODD,EVEN
TIGHT,BIND
UNION,COMPOSITE
```

**EDIT: added a few more examples, and fixed a mistake. (Note that PLOT is a Contradictory Word™, correctly pointed out by Yout Reid)**

Comment: Plot is not a contradictory word™?

Comment: @YoutRied, you are right!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> A Contradictory Word™ is a word that is not a valid solution to the Word™ puzzle on this site of the same word.

> Non-Contradictory Words™ all fit their secret rules:

> [Text Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/107044/what-is-a-text-word) Text is a word that appears in Baba Is You, according the accepted solution
>  [Late Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110224/what-is-a-late-word) The letters in the word Late alternate between vowels and consonants
>  [Explosive Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43189/what-is-an-explosive-word) The ASCII Codes in the odd numbered letters add up to 370, which is not odd, making this an explosive word
>  [Green Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/59053/what-is-a-green-word) N has an opening at the top, making it a green word
>  [Sharp Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110311/what-is-a-sharp-word) Sharp without the P can be rearranged to rash
>  [First Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/122347/what-is-a-contradictory-word) First becomes 10111 by replacing consonants with 1s and vowels with 0s, making 23, which is prime
>  [Even Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84200/what-is-an-even-word) 5 (e) + 22 (v) + 5 (e) + 14 (n) = 46, which is even
>  [Bind Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48882/what-is-a-bind-word) Bind is Bird with one letter misspelled
>  [Composite Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19982/what-is-a-composite-word) C + M + I = 1101, which is a composite number

> Contradictory Words™ are not valid Words™ for their secret rules:

> [Touch Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42175/what-is-a-touch-word) Lips don't touch each other or teeth when pronouncing "touch"
>  [Limited Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/97809/what-is-a-limited-word) 76 + 73 + 77 + 73 + 84 + 69 + 68 = 520, which is not 1 less than a power of 2
>  [Brutal Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/48588/what-is-a-brutal-word) Brutal doesn't give any other words under a rot Cipher
>  [Healthy Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/42382/what-is-a-healthy-word) The word healthy doesn't contain all the letters of a word for a colour of red as far as I can tell
>  [Cuddly Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43504/what-is-a-cuddly-word) There are no letters that you can add to the start and the end of the word cuddly that would make another word
>  [Final Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47081/what-is-a-final-word) [The word final doesn't appear in the KJV bible](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/search.php?hs=1&q=final)
>  [Odd Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/19857/what-is-an-odd-word) ODD has no ends. Lowercase odd has 2 ends, but that's still not an odd number of ends
>  [Tight Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/43016/what-is-a-tight-word) Tight has the letters t, g, and h, all of which are either ascenders or descenders, making tight not a tight word
>  [Union Word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86532/what-is-a-union-word) Uni is not a valid Alpha-3 country code

> Some words cannot be in either category because there isn't What is a Word™ puzzle with those words. Also, contradictory can't be either because that would create a paradox.

Comment: Nice... I will accept your answer when you also explain why some words cannot be either categories.

Comment: @CatProgrammer I've added an explanation of why some words don't fit into either category

Comment: @Youtreid, good job solving it despite my initial mistake. Rot13(Vs lbh hfr n0m25 vafgrnq, gura cybg vf n Cybg  Jbeq. )

Comment: Despite your spoilers, the "Linked Questions" section is now a pretty big spoiler ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @EngineerToast, I believe those only appeared only after the solution was posted :)